# How to compare function instance object with an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I wrote a test case for a function,where the expected object is like below,

```js
"point": {
  "events": {}
}
```

But what I am receiving is like below,

```js
"point": {
  "events": Object {
    "click": [Function click],
  }
```

The code of the function that I am testing,

```js
function testing() {
  "point": {
    "events": {
      "click": function() {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here my test case is getting failed because of this,can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: is click function generated or are you passing it as prop?

Answer (score -1):

your question is not clear, but you can do something like this. hope it helps

```js
function testFunct(){}
const emptyObj = {};

console.log(typeof testFunct)
console.log(typeof emptyObj)
```